# How do I sort objects in VB.net with custom comparer elegantly?

Tags: vb.net, sorting

I want to sort a bunch of domainsdata object. I want to sort first based on countryCode then I want to sort based on revenue.

First I created a private comparer.

```
Private Function CompareDomainCountry(ByVal x As domainsData, ByVal y As domainsData) As Integer
    If x.countryCode < y.countryCode Then
        Return -1
    ElseIf y.countryCode < x.countryCode Then
        Return 1
    ElseIf x.revenue < y.revenue Then
        Return 1
    ElseIf y.revenue < x.revenue Then
        Return -1
    Else
        Return 0
    End If
End Function
```

This has several problem.

The comparer returns 1,-1,0. I think there should be a normal enum for that.

Also I think my comparer should simply call standard vb.net comparer.

And after that, how do I sort list (of domainsdata)?

comparer?

Answer (score 2):

First, note that your Revenue compare code is inconsistent: a smaller X should return -1. You also don't absolutely need that method.  This gives the same result:

```
Dim sorted = DomainList.OrderBy(Function(x) x.CountryCode).
                         ThenBy(Function(y) y.Revenue).
                         ToList()
```

If you want to rely on a standard NET method, your method can be a class member:

```
Public Class DomainComparer
    Implements IComparer(Of Domain)

    Public Function Compare(x As Domain, y As Domain) As Integer _ 
                                         Implements IComparer(Of Domain).Compare
        ' all your code
    End Function
End Class
```

Then to use it:

```
Dim dSorter = New DomainComparer
DomainList.Sort(dSorter)
' or simply:
DomainList.Sort(New DomainComparer)
```

Mr Guffa's `AddressOf` method is simpler and more concise; I like the class method when there are other variables/properties such as a SortOrder.

The results are the same either way (when the revenue result is changed) unless a sort member is mixed alpha-numeric string (which seemed not to be the case based on the names and comparison).

If you were hoping to use your method with `OrderBy()`, I dont think you can - the signature doesn't match `Func(Of T)(TKey)`.  The return however is uniform with most all `Compare()` methods to indicate the larger value (`DateTime` indicates the lesser/earlier date; there may be others).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `CompareTo` method to compare the values. If the first comparison is zero, then do the other comparison:

```
Private Function CompareDomainCountry(ByVal x As domainsData, ByVal y As domainsData) As Integer
  Dim result As Integer = x.countryCode.CompareTo(y.countryCode)
  If result = 0 Then
    result = x.revenue.CompareTo(y.revenue)
  End If
  Return result
End Function
```

To sort the list using the comparison you use it in the `Sort` method call:

```
myList.Sort(AddressOf CompareDomainCountry)
```